# Support in solving the VBA Query?

Tags: excel, vba, quantitative-finance

```
Sub Purchase_Scenarios() (Initiating Purchase_Scenario Macro) 

Dim s As Integer 
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim x As Integer

Sheets("Scenario").Activate [want to go to Scenario sheet]

s = 1 
i = Range("H14").Value [assign value in cell H14 of Scenario sheet to variable i]
c = Range("I14").Value [assign value in cell i14 of Scenario sheet to variable c]
x = 3 [assign x=3]

Do While s <= x [run until s is less than x]

Range("G13").Value = s [assign the cell G13 in Scenario sheet with the current value of s]

Call Solve_All [call Solve_Al Macro that is running absolutely fine and the output is a solver value for Named Range Purchase]

Application.Goto Sheets("Inputs").Range("Purchase") [ go to inputs sheet and copy the named Range Purchase]
 
Range("Purchase").Copy [copy the value in  the cell]
Sheets("Scenario").Activate [Go to sheet named Scenario]

Range(Cells(i, c), Cells(i, c)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) [go to range (i,c)]

s = s + 1 [add 1 to variable s]
c = c + 1 [add 1 to c]

Loop [loop the above code till s<=x]

End Sub
```

There are two sheets named Scenario and Purchase. Solve_ALL is a solver macro already in place that solves for Purchase price.

Next to the code is a bit more explanation, and I hope this is a bit more clear.

I want to activate the Scenario Sheet and input the values from variable "s" to cell "G13". Then call the Solve_All Macro and copy the value from cell named Purchase in Inputs sheet. Then basically paste that to Cell (i,c); where i and c are variable that get their value from values in a predefined cell in Scenario sheet.

The loop through with "S" being 2 and run the same process and move a cell to the right last used cell "Cells (i, c), Cells (i, c))" in scenario for and paste the value that is being generated and repeat the process 10 times.

I need help in figuring this out.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? (i.e. show us your attempt to solve the problem and explain how it fails to achieve the desired result)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.